# I'm not able to add image uploads to my existing form | NextJS

Tags: javascript, image, forms, next.js, input

I want to save the images locally and save the path in the database. I've tried several methods but it always ends up giving me an error somewhere. I've never worked with uploading images so I'm having a lot of difficulty. Mainly because I was sending the form data in Json, but I can't send images like that.

I tried to make a formData but I couldn't adapt the api for that. I tried to convert to base64 to be able to send it via json and then deal with the image in the api but it also failed. I'm quite a beginner, can anyone help me?

I have the code on github if you want to check it out
Github: https://github.com/goncalojbsousa/onlinecloset_imgupld

Comment: As written, this question doesn't include some necessary specifics.  A link to the repo is good, but you should _also_ include a simple example of the code _in the question_ that allows people to reproduce your problem, and explain exactly what you see (error messages) when your code fails.  More guidance here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.